# KeyError: <type="str> while making migration in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a model and Tried to migrate it, it is throwing error.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank = True)
```

This is the error I am getting after creating the Model.
I am using mysql instead of sqlite3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 110, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 276, in get_new_connection
    conn.encoders[SafeBytes] = conn.encoders[bytes]
KeyError: <type 'str'>
```

EDIT:
Database setting
Using XAMPP mysql database -> localhost/phpmyadmin
In that I created djangoproject db

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangoproject',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your `DATABASES` setting - looks like the issue is with your database configuration rather than this particular migration.

Answer (score 10):

I had same issue.

Do this "pip list" and check the version of mysqlclient you have installed.
If >= 1.4; please do this instead. "pip install mysqlclient==1.3.14".

I got it to work that way. Apparently 1.4 is having some issues

Comment: Has mysqlclient been fixed to account for this issue? I've downgraded to 1.3.14 and this seems to be the only solution for now. Anyone been able to figure this out?

Comment: No. not yet fixed

Comment: for me it was only an issue when using python2...on a legacy project. newest versions could not be built, older versions had problems...1.3.14 was the way to go!